# Pivot without aggregate with only one column in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, pivot-table

I have a table with `ID`, `EmployeeNameHistory`, `CompanyWorked` columns

```
CREATE TABLE EMp
(
     ID int not null,
     EmployeeNameHistory varchar(200) not null, 
     CompanyWorked varchar(200) not null
)

INSERT INTO EMP (1, 'Jill Joane', 'Oracle corp')
INSERT INTO EMP (1, 'Jill Keane', 'Oracle corp')
INSERT INTO EMP (1, 'Jill Keane', 'Infosys')
INSERT INTO EMP (2, 'Anne Smith', 'Oracle corp')
INSERT INTO EMP (2, 'Anne Jordan', 'Infosys')
```

I want the output to only pivot by ID

```
1 (Jill Joane Oracle corp) (Jill Keane Oracle corp) (Jill Keane Infosys)
2 (Anne Smith Oracle corp) (Anne Jordan Infosys)
```

First column is `ID` , Second to n columns is `'(' + EmployeeNameHistory + CompanyWorked + ')'`

How can I do that?

Thanks
MR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option which operates off a distinct list of ids

```
Select A.ID
      ,History = (Select Stuff((Select ' (' +EmployeeNameHistory +' ' + CompanyWorked +')' From Emp Where ID=A.ID For XML Path ('')),1,1,'') )
 From (Select Distinct ID From Emp ) A
```

Returns

```
ID  History
1   (Jill Joane Oracle corp) (Jill Keane Oracle corp) (Jill Keane Infosys)
2   (Anne Smith Oracle corp) (Anne Jordan Infosys)
```

Answer (score 1):

### Query

```
SELECT e.ID 
     , STUFF(( SELECT ' (' + t.EmployeeNameHistory + ' ' + t.CompanyWorked + ')'
              FROM EMP t
              WHERE t.ID = e.ID
              FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
              .value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'') AS [Data]
FROM EMP e
GROUP BY e.ID
```

### Result Set

```
╔════╦════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║ ID ║                                  Data                                  ║
╠════╬════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║  1 ║ (Jill Joane Oracle corp) (Jill Keane Oracle corp) (Jill Keane Infosys) ║
║  2 ║ (Anne Smith Oracle corp) (Anne Jordan Infosys)                         ║
╚════╩════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not Pivot. You need to Concatenate the columns Data by grouping the ID

```
CREATE TABLE #EMp (ID INT NOT NULL, EmployeeNameHistory VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL, CompanyWorked VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL)

INSERT INTO #EMp
VALUES (1, 'Jill Joane', 'Oracle corp')

INSERT INTO #EMp
VALUES (1, 'Jill Keane', 'Oracle corp')

INSERT INTO #EMp
VALUES (1, 'Jill Keane', 'Infosys')

INSERT INTO #EMp
VALUES (2, 'Anne Smith', 'Oracle corp')

INSERT INTO #EMp
VALUES (2, 'Anne Jordan', 'Infosys')

--Here your query goes
SELECT *
FROM #EMp

SELECT DISTINCT ID, (
        SELECT ' ( ' + EmployeeNameHistory + '' + CompanyWorked + ')'
        FROM #EMP E2
        WHERE E1.ID = E2.ID
        FOR XML PATH('')
        ) AS EMP_COMP
FROM #EMP E1
```